# Get list of selected materials

Tags: python, outliner

Is there a way get the list of selected materials that are selected on the Blender File's Outliner space and do something with that recently get list?

This method doesn't depend on what object is selected and/or which material is assgined to waht object.

[image]

Comment: That gets the materials assigned to an object. In this case I need to get the names of the selected materials in the Blender file.

Comment: Have you tried the script ? It does exactly what you're asking for, I just tested it. Just remove the parts about collections and objects

Comment: Funny enoguh, not sure why it didn't work in 2.93, but it does in 3.0. I will accept your solution.